# Pandas groupby and perform arithmetic operations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe which I want to group by 3 columns and perform arithmetic operations to calculate a new column per group. This is what I tried till now:

```
df['c'] = df.groupby(['date', 'year', 'month']).apply(lambda x: sum(x['a']*x['weight'])/sum(x['b']*x['weight']))
```

but it throws this error:

> ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got
> 'long' During handling of the above exception, another exception
> occurred: TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame
> index

I also tried np.sum() function:

```
df['c'] = df.groupby(['date', 'year', 'month']).apply(lambda x: np.sum(x['a']*x['weight'])/np.sum(x['b']*x['weight']))
```

but it also throws the same error.

I am not sure if this is some issue with the data or my code.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need custom function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':['2010-01-01'] * 6,
         'year':[2004,2005,2004,2005,2005,2004],
         'month':[7] * 6,
         'a':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'b':[3,5,7,1,0,8],
         'weight':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'col':list('aaabbb')
})

def f(x):
    x['c'] = (x['a']*x['weight']).sum() /(x['b']*x['weight']).sum()
    return x

df = df.groupby(['date', 'year', 'month']).apply(f)
print (df)
         date  year  month  a  b  weight col         c
0  2010-01-01  2004      7  1  3       5   a  0.393258
1  2010-01-01  2005      7  3  5       3   a  3.083333
2  2010-01-01  2004      7  5  7       6   a  0.393258
3  2010-01-01  2005      7  7  1       9   b  3.083333
4  2010-01-01  2005      7  1  0       2   b  3.083333
5  2010-01-01  2004      7  0  8       4   b  0.393258
```